# Где ошибка в синтаксисе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пишу SQL запрос для создания таблицы со всеми полями (записями). СУБД - MySQL.

**Сам запрос:**

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  employee_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  middle_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  manager_id INT(6) NULL,
  job_id INT(6) NULL,
  hire_date DATE NULL,
  salary FLOAT(7,2) NULL,
  commission FLOAT(7,2) NULL,
  department_id INT(6) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
  INDEX dep_idx (department_id ASC),
  INDEX emp_idx (manager_id ASC),
  INDEX jobi_idx job_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT dep
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
    REFERENCES ikbo_11_18.department (department_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT emp
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
    REFERENCES ikbo_11_18.employee (employee_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT jobi
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id)
    REFERENCES ikbo_11_18.job (job_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

**Ошибка:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'job_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT dep
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
    REFERENCES ikb' at line 15
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то не хватает скобочки в `INDEX jobi_idx job_id ASC),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ровно там, где написано в сообщении:

> near 'job_id ASC)

а вот строка целиком

```
INDEX jobi_idx job_id ASC),
```

кто скобку открывать будет?